# react error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Can someone help me please. I'm just learning react and i'm getting this error as i start to implement  my Navbar Component and add some material-ui element to it.

Error:

> ```
> Unexpected Application Error!
> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
>     at Object.useContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58534:25)
>     at useTheme (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53459:59)
>     at useTheme (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53369:77)
>     at useThemeProps (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53424:68)
>     at useThemeProps (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50503:65)
>     at SvgIcon (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49311:82)
>     at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25325:22)
>     at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:27896:24)
>     at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29943:20)
>     at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34870:18)
> ```

Here is my Code

Apps.js

> ```
> App.js without the imports
>
> const Layout = () =>{
>   return(
>     <div className="app">
>         <Navbar/>
>         <Outlet/>
>         <Footer/>
>         footer
>     </div>
>   )
> }
> const router = createBrowserRouter([
>   {
>     path:"/",
>     element: <Layout/>,
>     children:[
>       {
>         path:"/",
>         element: <Home/>
>       },
>     ]
>   },
> ]);
>
> function App() {
>   return (
>     <div className="App">
>        <RouterProvider router={router} />
>     </div>
>   );
> }
> export default App;
> ```

Navbar.jsx without the imports

> ```
> <div className='left'>
>            <div className="item">
>                 <MenuOutlinedIcon/>
>            </div>
>            <div className="item">
>                 <Link to= "/">Blog</Link>
>            </div>
>         </div>
>   </div>
> ```

Comment: Share the entire Navbar components.
You are probably using useContext which is null.

Comment: Hey, thank for your response and I just posted the entire Navbar Component

Answer (score 0):

Here ist my entire Navbar Component.

> ```
> import React from 'react'
> import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
> import FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorderOutlined';
> import PersonOutlineOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PersonOutlineOutlined';
> import ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCartOutlined';
> import MenuOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MenuOutlined';
> import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
> const Navbar = () => {
>   return (
>     <div className='navbar'>
>       <div className='wrapper'>
>         <div className='left'>
>            <div className="item">
>                 <MenuOutlinedIcon/>
>            </div>
>            <div className="item">
>                 <Link to= "/">Blog</Link>
>            </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       
>     </div>
>   )
> }
>
> export default Navbar
> ```

Comment: You should have added it in quesetion section.